# C++ bind function for use as argument of other function

Tags: c++, bind

I have a function that requires a function pointer as argument:

```
int func(int a, int (*b)(int, int))
{
    return b(a,1);
}
```

Now I want to use a certain function that has three arguments in this function:

```
int c(int, int, int)
{
    // ...
}
```

How can I bind the first argument of `c` so that I'm able to do:

```
int i = func(10, c_bound);
```

I've been looking at `std::bind1st` but I cannot seem to figure it out. It doesn't return a function pointer right? I have full freedom to adapt `func` so any changes of approach are possible. Althoug I would like for the user of my code to be able to define their own `c`...

note that the above is a ferocious simplification of the actual functions I'm using.

The project sadly requires `C++98`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't do that. You would have to modify `func` to take a function-object first. Something like:

```
int func( int a, std::function< int(int, int) > b )
{
    return b( a, rand() );
}
```

In fact, there is no need for `b` to be an `std::function`, it could be templated instead:

```
template< typename T >
int func( int a, T b )
{
    return b( a, rand() );
}
```

but I would stick with the `std::function` version for clarity and somewhat less convoluted compiler output on errors.

Then you would be able to do something like:

```
int i = func( 10, std::bind( &c, _1, _2, some-value ) );
```

Note all this is **C++11**, but you can do it in **C++03** using Boost.

Comment: even though I needed c++98 code, this answer was easily converted into it's boost equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you know at compile time, what you have to bind c with, you could define a new function

```
int c_bound(int a, int b) {
   return c(a,b,some_value);
}
```

That's obviously not a generic solution but might solve your current problem. Otherwise K-ballo's solution seems to be the only easy generic one. However, that requires you to be able to change the signature of `func`. If you really have an API that you can't touch the signature, and you still need to bind an argument AND if the above solution doesn't solve your specific case: (Caution, overkill ahead) I've always wanted to use an [LLVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) based solution to compile a function at runtime and pass its address in such situations.

Answer (score 0):

You would be unable to use a 3 argument function as a 2 argument function;  Mainly because there is no real way to determine what the 3rd parameter would do.

While the above answer would work, here is another option:

If one of the parameters for `c()`, in use within `func`, is constant, you could write a wrapper function for `c(int, int, int)`:

```
int d(int a, int b)
{
   return c(a, b, 0); //use a constant parameter
}
```

or, if you can determine the 3rd parameter from the two given parameters, you can also try:

```
int e(int a, int b)
{
    int extra = 0;
    ///Determine extra from a, and b
    return c(a, b, c);
}
```