# C++ Lambda, how is the capture clause deep inside

Tags: c++, lambda

When I have a callback function like this:

```
using MessageCallback =
    std::function<void(const Message &, uint64_t deliveryTag, bool redelivered)>;
```

I could declare a static callback function inside a class:

```
static void MessageCB(const AMQP::Message &message,
                      uint64_t deliveryTag,
                      bool redelivered)
{...}
```

But I'm not able to access any Member variables inside this Callback Function.

When I write a Lambda Function like this:

```
 auto MessageCB= [&](const AMQP::Message &message,
                      uint64_t deliveryTag,
                      bool redelivered)
 {...}
```

I could then use any member variables from the context where I declared the lambda.

How is this working?
How exactly is the capture clause working?

What is the difference to a static callback function?

Comment: As I read your question, I think you are asking what is/how does a lambda work?  This is probably too broad for SO.

Comment: No, I undestand how to use it, but I want to undestand how a Lamda enables the access to the capure clause. What is the is the equivalent in c++ 03? How could I rewrite a lamda with a static callback function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This cpp reference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) explains how Lambda expressions are formed, the following is from the *captures* section (my emphasis):

> [&] captures all automatic variables used in the body of the lambda by reference and **current object by reference if exists**

If you are asking specifically how does the compiler capture variables when declaring them in a Lambda then [this](https://blog.feabhas.com/2014/03/demystifying-c-lambdas/) is a useful resource. From that page:

> When you add a capture list to a lambda the compiler adds appropriate member variables to the lambda-functor class and a constructor for initialising these variables.[image]

Answer (score 0):

> No, I undestand how to use it, but I want to undestand how a Lamda
>   enables the access to the capure clause. What is the is the equivalent
>   in c++ 03? How could I rewrite a lamda with a static callback
>   function? – selbolder

Look at [boost bind](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html)

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692121/c-bind-function-for-use-as-argument-of-other-function)